# Dropdown menu appears even mouse hovers on other areas on the web page

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Am using the below drop down for my site header menu.

https://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/364/index.html

In this, When mouse hovering below spaces of the menu also Dropdown menu appearing. 
I used this code in my site. I wasn't able to find out whats the solution. 
I tried z-indexing and position as relative but still it appears. please guide me.

Thanks.

yes `z-index` but it a minus value like `z-index:-100;`

Comment: It is a strange issue, but your question here on SO has little persistent value to the community unless you put your code in the question, or at least in a demo (http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

I checked the plugin the problem is your action happens when you hover li and the sub-menu is present inside li. So that is the reason whatever element that comes inside of li will be part of li.

You can do 1 thing in this scenario:

Best Solution:

```
.submenu{height:0;}
```

Let me know if this works!!